# Run a binary from .app's package contents

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, shell

Can I have the binary files like .sh as part of the .app in "Package Contents".

I basically have .app which has 2 buttons start/stop which basically kicks off a process to start the server. To keep everything clean, I would like to store the start/stop shell scripts within the .app.

Can I execute those shell scripts from .app?

Comment: If you are on Lion, you should use an XPC Service....

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac, yes: use the NSTask class’s `+launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:arguments:` method (for example), after retrieving the path to the binaries with one of the methods on NSBundle’s—`-resourcePath`, `-bundlePath`, `-pathForResource:ofType:`, or whatever.

On iOS... no. NSTask isn’t available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You'll want to look at NSTask to run your scripts or other binaries, and find the files using NSBundle's API.